# Google Games: Gingerbread w/ Multiple G+ Accounts > Indefinite Sign-In Loop - GameHelper

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games, shiva3d

With Google Play Game Services samples, If you use a Gingerbread device that has multiple Google Accounts, you cannot sign in. GameHelper fails to sign-in and you get stuck in a never ending "sign-in screen" loop.

If you open GameHelper.java and comment out line 417: mExpectingResolution = false;

..then you can actually log in. But this also causes my game to crash.

Google Play Services and a new class GameHelper with an example ButtonClicker2000 on android 2.3 can not log in to your account. When a dialog box (sign-in dialog) appears with the user's choice, the method onStop().

```
/** Call this method from your Activity's onStop(). */
public void onStop() {
    debugLog("onStop");
    assertConfigured("onStop");
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        debugLog("Disconnecting client due to onStop");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    } else {
        debugLog("Client already disconnected when we got onStop.");
    }
    mConnecting = false;
    mExpectingResolution = false;

    // let go of the Activity reference
    mActivity = null;
}
```

After selecting the user calls the onStart(). However, there is no sign-in. Instead Development dialog box (sign-in dialog) reappears with the user's choice. And so indefinitely.

```
/** Call this method from your Activity's onStart(). */
public void onStart(Activity act) {
    mActivity = act;
    mAppContext = act.getApplicationContext();

    debugLog("onStart");
    assertConfigured("onStart");

    if (mConnectOnStart) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.w(TAG,
                    "GameHelper: client was already connected on onStart()");
        } else {
            debugLog("Connecting client.");
            mConnecting = true;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        debugLog("Not attempting to connect becase mConnectOnStart=false");
        debugLog("Instead, reporting a sign-in failure.");
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyListener(false);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Is there any fix for the log-in loop bug in GameHelper?

The source is here: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

Comment: Can you at least link to the sample code?

Comment: Updated my post, thank you! https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

Comment: Can you also post the logs?

Comment: I can't figure out how to get GameHelper to log anything, it has a 
boolean mDebugLog but setting true still won't show any logs.

Comment: [This post](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/48) isn't the same issue as yours but *may* help.  Scroll down to the guys with multiple G+ accounts problem.

Comment: Can you please try Trivial Quest: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/TrivialQuest

This sample avoids usage of BaseGameActivity and may be helpful.